# How is it possible to program an ATTiny over USB without a USB to TTL chip?

Tags: serial, attiny85

I have been testing out my [Digispark](http://digistump.com/products/1) and the board has no USB to TTl converter chip and yet you can program it over USB. Is it possible to do this with an ATmega328p for example?

Comment: a guess: the chip on the board is preloaded with a bootloader that implements a usb device and can program itself using data received through usb.

Comment: See e.g. https://www.obdev.at/products/vusb/index.html. It's a firmware for AVR µCs which makes it possible to do a pure software emulation of low-speed USB.

Comment: https://www.obdev.at/products/vusb/bootloadhid-de.html

Comment: This software USB scheme is somewhat possible on an ATmega as well, but it actually works better on the tiny due to some unique features there.